# perl script to telnet an eagle stp device

Tags: perl

I need to a script that telnet to eagle STP device and run commands there.

When I try to telnet a eagle STP device from command prompt,

I am getting the below output :

```
[root@localhost tmp]# telnet hostname port
Trying hostname...
Connected to hostname hostname).
Escape character is '^]'.
```

I am not getting any prompt here to match in the perl script. We need to press control+a inorder to get the prompt.If we press control+a, it will give the below output

```
[root@localhost tmp]# telnet hostname port
Trying...
Connected to hostname.
Escape character is '^]'.


>
```

Then we need to enter login:uid at this prompt

```
> login:uid=dumps
```

Then it prompts for a password

```
Enter password : password
```

then again we need to press control+a again to execute the commands.

```
> rtrv-dstn.
```

I am struck here , I am unable to pass control+a command after telnet command.

I wrote the script in the below way. But it is not working. Can ANY ONE HELP ME !!!!

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Net::Telnet;
my $host='hostname';
my $port='port';
my $telnet = new Net::Telnet(Host => $host, Port => $port, Timeout => 20)
or die "connect failed: $!";
$telnet->open($host);
print"Hi iii";
$telnet->waitfor('+$/i');');
print"Hello";
$telnet->print("^]");
$telnet->waitfor('/>$/i');
$telnet->print("login:uid=username");
$telnet->waitfor('/Enter Password :\s+$/i');
$telnet->print("password");
$telnet->waitfor('/>$/i');
@res1=$telnet->print("rtrv-dstn");
print"@res1";
Exit;
```

Comment: `^]`  is normally interpreted by the local telnet-client! Its not sent to the remote host!

Answer (score 1):

From [Net::Telnet](https://metacpan.org/module/Net%3a%3aTelnet):

> #### print - write to object
>
> This method writes `@list` **followed by the *output record separator*** to the open object and returns 1 if all data was successfully written. On time-out or other failures, the error mode action is performed. See errmode().

You can set the output_record_separtor via `$telnet->ors("\x01");` or by using:

```
$telnet->cmd("\x01");
```

to send a `Ctrl-A` when you need it. Don't have an Eagle STP for testing, but I hope this helps.

By the way, you should **always** check the output of each method call to make sure it works.

Answer (score 1):

I dont have your device to try out, but you could try to use the metasymbols and send `"\cA"` for CTRL-A:

```
$telnet->print("\cA");
```

Also `^]` is used by the local telnet client to escape sequences not sending them directly to the server, so i suppose it has no use here.

Comment: The above code is not working after modifications you said also.

I have a linux server, where I need to press control+]. I am unable to do this also:

[root@testams0005 tmp]# telnet 172.16.14.46 9080
Trying 172.16.14.46...
Connected to 172.16.14.46 (172.16.14.46).
Escape character is '^]'.
^]
telnet> help

Comment: I wrote the same script for this also. But it is not working. I sit possible to you test in your server please.

    #!/usr/bin/perl
    use Net::Telnet;
    my $host='hostname';
    my $port='port';
    my $telnet = new Net::Telnet(Host => $host, Port => $port,   Timeout => 20)
    or die "connect failed: $!";
    $telnet->open($host);
    print"Hi iii";
    $telnet->print("\x01");
    print"Hello";
    $telnet->waitfor('/telnet >\');
    @res1=$telnet->print("help");
    print"@res1";
    Exit;

Comment: I am getting the below error.

[root@testams0005 ~]# perl telnet.pl 
Can't find string terminator "'" anywhere before EOF at telnet.pl line 11.

If I comment-out the line $telnet->waitfor('/telnet >\'); .Output is as follows :

[root@testams0005 ~]# perl telnet.pl 
Hi iiiHello1

I am not getting the output of help command. I am just getting1 here.

Please help me if you can I working on this from 1 week and no luck.

Comment: This error comes from this `$telnet->waitfor('/telnet >\')`: You mask the `'` with the ` \ ` So write it like this: `$telnet->waitfor("\/telnet \>\\");`

Comment: The other thing is that this escape sequence `^]`is used by your commandline telnet-client (most likely the program `telnet`) for stuff not sending to the server like its help-text and some control stuff. None of this comes from the server resp. the machine you log into. I think its simply not available with `Net::Telnet`.

Comment: actually  I am getting problem at matching part. Immediately after telnet we will some thing to match when it prompts us for username or password or if some string exists after entering the telnet command.

Comment: But my problem is nothing displayed after telnet, it just goes into a new line with cursor.I am unable to match it. If could match it then I could send further signals like \cA......MATCHING BECAME A BIG PROBLEM FOR ME. I am going on changing the patterns but it is not at all working

Answer (score 0):

$telnet->print("\cA") will not likely work as it also sends a trailing newline.  Use put() to send chars without the trailing newline e.g. $telnet->put("\cA");